# React app runs locally but fails with unexpected token '<' when pushed to heroku (prod)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, heroku, webpack, babeljs

I've been refactoring my webpack config for two reasons. First, to remove `extract-text-webpack-plugin` from it since it's deprecated and apparently i should be using `MiniCssExtractPlugin` instead for css. Second, it seemed like a good idea to use `splitChunks` to have a seperate js and css file for my code vs everything in node_modules. It seems to be working great save one problem, when I run a heroku push and then try to load my app, the browser throws a `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'` error in the console and i get a blank page.

- It runs fine under dev-server.
- It runs fine under heroku local.
- I've gone through heroku's troubleshooting page and don't see anything with versioning, gitignore, node_modules, etc.
- I've spent half of today googling this error and reading other stack overflow articles to no avail. It seems as though the basic problem relates to the browser expecting js but it's getting html. something to do with not transplining properly? So i was thinking perhaps something was going on with my babel config and the now multiple files but admit i don't know if i'm on the right track (e.g. `vendor.build.js` file isn't transplining properly?).
- So i suspect the problem relates to splitting my output files up somehow..

About the only thing that looks any different to me are the files that get produced when i run a dev build vs a production build although i'm not sure that's the source of the problem or not. Clearly i'm doing something wrong but i'm at a loss as to what.

screenshot of browser error:

[image]

here is what the unexpected token error is pointing to in `vendors.bundle.js`. This is my app's `index.html` file btw:

[image: here is what the unexpected token error is pointing to in vendors.bundle.js]

a dev build produces 4 files after my above refactoring exercise and based on the below webpack config:

[image]

A prod build produces more files:

[image]

my `webpack.config.js` file looks like this:

```
const path = require("path");
const webpack = require("webpack");
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
// const BundleAnalyzerPlugin = require('webpack-bundle-analyzer').BundleAnalyzerPlugin;

process.env.NODE_ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV || "development";

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "test") {
  require("dotenv").config({ path: ".env.test" });
} else if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "development") {
  require("dotenv").config({ path: ".env.development" });
}

module.exports = (env) => {
  const isProduction = env === "production";

  return {
    entry: ["babel-polyfill", "./src/app.js"],
    output: {
      path: path.join(__dirname, "public", "dist"),
      filename: "bundle.js",
    },
    optimization: {
      splitChunks: {
        cacheGroups: {
          default: false,
          vendor: {
            test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
            name: 'vendors',
            chunks: 'all'
          },
        },
      },
    },
    mode: isProduction ? 'production' : 'development',
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          loader: "babel-loader",
          test: /\.js$/,
          exclude: /node_modules/,
        },
        {
          test: /\.less$/,
            use: [
              {
                loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                options: {
                  sourceMap: !isProduction,
                },
              },
              {
                loader: "css-loader",
                options: {
                  sourceMap: !isProduction,
                },
              },
              {
                loader: "less-loader",
                options: {
                  sourceMap: !isProduction,
                  modifyVars: {
                    "primary-color": "#1c88bf",
                    "link-color": "#1c88bf",
                    "border-radius-base": "2px",
                  },
                  javascriptEnabled: true,
                },
              }
            ],
        },
        {
          test: /\.s?css$/,
          use: [
            {
              loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
              options: {
                sourceMap: !isProduction,
              },
            },
            {
              loader: "css-loader",
              options: {
                sourceMap: !isProduction,
              },
            },
            {
              loader: "sass-loader",
              options: {
                sourceMap: !isProduction,
              },
            },
          ],
        },
        {
          test: /\.(svg|eot|ttf|woff|woff2)$/,
          use: {
            loader: "file-loader",
            options: {
              name: "[name].[ext]",
              outputPath: "fonts/",
            },
          },
        },
      ],
    },
    plugins: [
      // new BundleAnalyzerPlugin(),
      new MiniCssExtractPlugin({ filename: '[name].css'}),
      new webpack.DefinePlugin({
        "process.env.FIREBASE_API_KEY": JSON.stringify(process.env.FIREBASE_API_KEY),
        "process.env.FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN": JSON.stringify(process.env.FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN),
        "process.env.FIREBASE_DATABASE_URL": JSON.stringify(process.env.FIREBASE_DATABASE_URL),
        "process.env.FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID": JSON.stringify(process.env.FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID),
        "process.env.FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET": JSON.stringify(process.env.FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET),
        "process.env.FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID": JSON.stringify(process.env.FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID),
      }),
    ],
    devtool: isProduction ? "source-map" : "inline-source-map",
    devServer: {
      contentBase: path.join(__dirname, "public"),
      historyApiFallback: true,
      publicPath: "/dist/",
    },
  };
};
```

my `.babelrc` file for what it's worth..

```
{
  "presets": [
    "@babel/preset-env",
    "@babel/preset-react"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread",
    [
      "import",
      {
        "libraryName": "antd",
        "libraryDirectory": "es",
        "style": "true"
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

turns out the problem in my case was the fact that the filenames above different between the development and production builds (see above screenshots). Consequently, my index.html was referring to the wrong filenames for the production build (see above index.html script tags).

I ultimately fixed it with two changes. First, i fixed my webpack config to output the same filenames for both dev and prod builds. This wasn't immediately obvious to me as to how to do this (i wasn't sure why dev was using `vendors.bundle.js` and prod was using `1.bundle.js`) but it ended up being trivial. In the output section i simply had to change the filename parameter from `"bundle.js"` to `"[name].js"`.

the new filenames:

[image]

the `webpack.config.js` change:

```
    output: {
      path: path.join(__dirname, "public", "dist"),
      filename: "[name].js",
    },
```

Then, I built both the dev and prod builds to confirm that the filenames were now the same. Once I realized they were, I modified my `index.html` to use those two filenames from before..

```
  <script src="/dist/vendors.js"></script>
  <script src="/dist/main.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears that your call to the js file is returning your index.html, which is why the browser is complaining about the `<`. Check if there is some routing misconfigured that would return index.html if nothing hits and then look for why it's not matching.